# Auto-create a view in different schemas SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Let's say I have 3 schemas : Japan, Europe, America and I have 1 view with the same name in every schema. I want to modify/create 1 view from schema 'Europe' and then replicate the view in Japan and America automatically.

Is it posible?

Comment: Change the schema and push the Execute button again.

Comment: Why different schemas?

Comment: You could create a DDL trigger but that seems like it could go really wrong for unsuspecting users creating other things that aren't supposed to follow that model...

Comment: That is not an ideal way to update a view

Comment: @JacobH Thanks for your reply. That's exactly the thing I need to do automatically.

Comment: @BibinMatthew What could be the ideal way?

Comment: I would suggest NOT to do it fully automated... Rather I would suggest to spool the "USE... ALTER VIEW..." from SYS.SCHEMAS and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS, store it somewhere for documenatation reasons and excute the spooled script. However, you COULD auptomate this with dyn. SQL, but still: wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

My work around as follows:

```
declare @mivar varchar(50)
declare Cursor1 cursor 
 for select SCHEMA_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_OWNER='dbo'
open Cursor1
--Fetch next from Cursor1
fetch Cursor1 into @mivar
while (@@fetch_status = 0) 
begin
    exec('Create view '+@mivar+' .MView as Select * from Sales.Store')
    fetch Cursor1 into @mivar
end
close Cursor1
DEALLOCATE  Cursor1
;
```